# How to find indefinte integral $\int_{0}^{\sqrt\pi} 2x\cos(\frac{x^2}{4})dx$ using substitution of $u=\cos(\frac{x^2}{4})$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Can someone help me find $\int_{0}^{\sqrt\pi} 2x\cos(\frac{x^2}{4})dx$ using the substitution $u=\cos(\frac{x^2}{4})$ step-by-step?

All I've done so far is:
$$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{2}x\sin(\frac{x^2}{4})$$
and
$$x=\sqrt\pi \longrightarrow u=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$
$$x=0 \longrightarrow u=1$$
$$\therefore \int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}\frac{-4u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$
This is where I don't know how to continue, can ayone help me understand how to finish this off?

Comment: Why not try the substitution $u=\frac{x^2}4$? As to the last integral, use the substitution $v=1-u^2$.

Comment: Do you mean, $\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}} -4uv^{-\frac{1}{2}}du$? But how would I integrate this?

Comment: With regards to your comment reply, you forgot that also $dv = -2du$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your steps
\begin{align*}
&\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{-4u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}du\\
=&~2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} \quad \text{on the substituion } (1 - u^2) = t\\
=&~2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{w}{w}d\omega\quad \text{on the substituition } t = \omega^2\\
=&~4 \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg] = 2\sqrt{2} 
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a great answer. Just one question though, how did you know to make $t=1-u^2$ so that the $u$ cancel?

Comment: Umm... Let's see this. Normally we want something easy to work with. Then we have a very trivial option of $\sqrt{1 - u^2} = t^2$. But it doesn't work. Then our primary target was $\sqrt{1 - u^2} = t$. And of course, I knew how these kinds of substitutions work ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are halfway there

Let $ 1-u^2=t \implies -2udu=dt$

Replace it $$\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}\frac{-4u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\int_0^{1\over2}\frac{2}{\sqrt t}dt$$

Thus the integral becomes$$2\int_0^{1\over2} t^{-1\over2}dt$$ which can be easily evaluated to $4\sqrt t$

Plugging in the limits gives the value of integral as $2\sqrt2$